# datagrid Remove row failed when second loop?

Tags: c#, for-loop, foreach, datagridview, rows

Is the remove method correct? I try to remove those unnecessary rows base column status. But I have failed to remove row when happen at second loop.

I have try to add continue but doesn't work, the error message I get is ("***Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.***").
only I add break and it's work for remove row(remove only one row, I want keep looping and remove row by the detection).

```
       if (queryResult.Rows != null) 
       {

      // now the query would display 10 rows
      DataTable dt_Details = new DataTable();
      dt_Details = queryResult.GetAsDataTable();

      foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt_Details.Rows)
      {
                    List<Array> newArrayList = new List<Array> ();
                    int A_TotalCount = 0;
                    int P_TotalCount = 0;
                    int C_TotalCount = 0;
                    if (dtRow["STATUS"].ToString() == "ACTIVE")
                    {
                        A_TotalCount++;
                    }
                    else if (dtRow["STATUS"].ToString() == "PROCESS")
                    {
                        P_TotalCount++;
                    }
                    else if (dtRow["STATUS"].ToString() == "COMPLETED")
                    {
                        C_TotalCount++;
                    }

                if ((P_TotalCount > 0 && A_TotalCount > 0 && C_TotalCount > 0) || (P_TotalCount > 0 && A_TotalCount > 0 && C_TotalCount == 0))
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt_Details.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row["Status"].ToString() == "ACTIVE")
                            dt_Details.Rows.Remove(row);
                    }
                }
                else if ((P_TotalCount == 0 && A_TotalCount > 0 && C_TotalCount > 0))
                {
                    foreach (DataRow row in dt_Details.Rows)
                    {
                        if (row["WaferStatus"].ToString() == "COMPLETED")
                            **dt_Details.Rows.Remove(row);**
                    }
                }              
      }
    }
```

Comment: Just e piece of advice. I really doubt that there are a lot of people that will read all these explanations before jumping into the code. Even if someone read them (like me) I doubt that all of them will understand the business logic and the actual problem that you have from the first pass (again like me). So why don't you try to cut some explanation and stick to the actual problem and the code that you have so far related to this problem?

Comment: Hi, Leron. I understand what you mean. I just try to explain more about what will happen for each transaction. The issue I faced is about how to get the checked result as an array list and pass into grid. There would have different case base on the status (ACTIVE, PROCESS, COMPLETED) it would change based on each submit transaction.

Comment: Well, if I were you I would try to edit the question, removing as much of the business logic as possible focusing on the actual issue. So far I can see three `if-else` clauses which makes it hard even to guess what could be the actual problem that you try to solve, but whatever. Just my 5 cents. I'll stop writing to avoid spamming your question.

Comment: The error is clear… _”Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute”_ … this means you are trying to “MODIFY” a “COLLECTION” in an “ENUMERATION” … to clarify this, you are using a `foreach` loop through all the rows in the grid… `foreach (DataRow dtRow in dt_Details.Rows)` … THEN INSIDE this `foreach` loop the code attempts to “DELETE” a row from the “COLLECTION” of rows. You can NOT “add” or “delete” items in the collection the `foreach` loop is iterating through. This is why you are getting the error.

Comment: If you want to delete the rows based on some value in the row… then I recommend you use a basic `for` loop through all the rows AND loop through the rows starting FROM THE BOTTOM UP. Example… `for (int i = dt_Details.Rows.Count -1; i >= 0; i--) {…if condition  delete row…}`.

Comment: Yes, I used this is work.Thank you @JohnG